# Java - how to get a key object (or entry) stored in HashMap by key?

Tags: java, dictionary, key

I'd like to get the "canonical" key object for each key usable to query a map. See here:

```
Map<UUID, String> map = new HashMap();
UUID a = new UUID("ABC...");
map.put(a, "Tu nejde o zamykání.");

UUID b = new UUID("ABC...");
String string = map.get(b); // This gives that string.

// This is what I am looking for:
UUID againA = map.getEntry(b).key();
boolean thisIsTrue = a == againA;
```

A `HashMap` uses `equals()`, which is the same for multiple unique objects. So I want to get the actual key from the map, which will always be the same, no matter what object was used to query the map.

Is there a way to get the actual key object from the map? I don't see anything in the interface, but perhaps some clever trick I overlooked?

(Iterating all entries or keys doesn't count.)

Comment: For what purpose? The only times you care about the actual object identity is if you are either synchronising or misusing `==`. NB a hash map uses both `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Re: "A `HashMap` uses `hashCode()`, which is the same for multiple unique objects": More relevantly, it uses `equals()` rather than `==`. The `hashCode()` is just for quickly narrowing down the set of keys that it needs to use `equals()` on.

Comment: I think it is very clear what I am asking, and just someone's taste for questions doesn't make this eligible to close for "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: What is unclear both this time and the previous time you asked this question is *why you are asking it.* At least last time you had a reason, although the code you posted was actually meaningless. This time, nothing, not even when you were specifically asked for an explanation, 23 minutes and several edits ago.

Comment: If your design depends on getting a reference to a specific instance, the key instance that was originally passed to `put(K,V)`, and an equivalent (via `hashCode()` and `equals()`) is insufficient, then your design is broken.  Unless you can provide a convincing reason for wanting this we have to assume it's an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: _Why_ I ask does not matter. It's a valid question. Otherwise you could ask "why" for each answer I give to your previous why. I understand you want to be helpful with the underlying problem, but if you don't want to answer it, fine. Please let others. Thanks.

Comment: The obvious answer is "no". But there are tricks. Like, "is it possible to create a singleton across all classloaders?" Simple wrong answer: no. Correct answer: Yes, with some hacks.

Comment: You could 'wrap' the String in an object that also stores the key, and put that wrapper in the map - but you must ensure that the correct key is stored (extending the Map?!)

Comment: Why you ask *does* matter: when the question appears pointless; when you are asked; when what you are asking looks like an XY problem; and when your previous motivation for asking it proved spurious. Are you perhaps looking for [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)?

Comment: Sorry, but my experience with "why do you ask" is that it leads to pointless discussions about other topic. This is a Q&A site, not a support site. Thanks for trying to help me with concurrency but I have a hotfix to do and know the fix, I only wanted to know if there's a trick to get the key object or should I create another map. Typically, hotfixes are not supposed to be fixing a bad syncing design.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the actual key object from the map?

<sup>OK, so I am going to make some assumptions about what you mean.  After all, you said that your question doesn't need clarification, so the obvious meaning that I can see **must be** the correct one.  Right? :-)</sup>

The answer is No.  There isn't a way.

Example scenario (not compileable!)

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("xxxx-yyy-zzz");
UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString("xxxx-yyy-zzz");  // same string
println(uuid == uuid2);  // prints false
println(uuid.equals(true));  // prints true

Map<UUID, String> map = new ...
map.put(uuid, "fred");
println(map.get(uuid)); // prints fred
println(map.get(uuid2)); // prints fred (because uuid.equals(uuid2) is true)
```

... but, the `Map` API does not provide a way to find the *actual* key (in the example above it is `uuid`) in the `map` apart from iterating the key or entry sets.  And I'm not aware of any existing `Map` class (standard or 3rd-party) that does provide this<sup>1</sup>.

However, you *could* implement your own `Map` class with an additional method for returning the actual key object.  There is no *technical* reason why you couldn't, though you would have more code to write, test, maintain, etcetera.

---

But I would add that I agree with Jim Garrison.  If you have a scenario where you have UUID objects (with equality-by-value semantics) and you also want to implement equality by identity semantics, then there is probably something wrong with your application's design.  The correct approach would be to change the `UUID.fromString(...)` implementation to always return the same `UUID` object for the same input string.

---

<sup>1 - This is not to say that such a map implementation doesn't exist.  But if it does, *you* should be able to find it if you look hard enough  Note that Questions asking us to find or recommend a library are off-topic!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There is a (relatively) simple way of doing this.  I’ve done so in my applications from time to time, when needed ... not for the purpose of `==` testing, but to reduce the number of identical objects being stored when tens of thousand of objects exist, and are cross-referenced with each other.  This significantly reduced my memory usage, and improved performance ... while still using `equals()` for equality tests.

Just maintain a parallel map for interning the keys.

```
Map<UUID, UUID> interned_keys = ...

UUID key = ...
if (interned_keys.contains(key))
    key = interned_keys.get(key)
```

Of course, it is far better when the object being stored knows what its own identity is.  Then you get the interning basically for free.

```
class Item {
    UUID key;
    // ...
}

Map<UUID, Item> map = ...
map.put(item.key, item);

UUID key = ...
key = map.get(key).key;  // get interned key
```

Comment: But the additional map will use up memory. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are valid reasons for wanting the actual key. For example, to save memory.  Also keep in mind that the actual key may store other objects. For instance, suppose you have a vertex of a graph. The vertex can store the actual data (Say a String, for instance), as well as the incident vertices. A vertex hash value can be dependent only on the data.  So to look up a vertex with some data, 
D, look up a vertex with data, D,and with with no incident values.  Now if you can return the actual vertex in the map you will be able to get the actual incident to the vertex.

It seems to me that many map implementations could easily provide a getEntry method.  For example, the HashMap implementation for get is:

```
  public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V> e;
    return (e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null ? null : e.value;
  }

  final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

One could use the getNode method to return an Entry:

```
 public getEntry(Object key){
   Node<K,V> e = getNode(hash(key),key);
   if(e == null) return null;
   return new Entry<>(e.key,e.value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to duplicate the reference to the key in the value using a generic Pair type, like this:

```
HashMap<UUID,Pair<UUID,String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

When you put them in the map, you provide the reference to the key to the pair. The cost is one reference per entry.

```
void add(UUID uuid, String str)
{
    myMap.put(uuid,Pair.of(uuid,str));
}

Pair<UUID,String> get(UUID uuid)
{
    return myMap.get(uuid);
}
```

Then getFirst() of the Pair *is* your key. getSecond() is the value.

Whatever you do, it's going to cost you in either time or space.

Your Pair class will be something like:

```
public class Pair<A,B>
{
    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    
    public Pair(A a, B b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    /**
     * @return      the first argument of the Pair
     */
    public A getFirst()
    {
        return this.a;
    }

    /**
     * @return      the second argument of the Pair
     */
    public B getSecond()
    {
        return this.b;
    }

    /**
     * Create a Pair.
     *
     * @param a         The first argument (of type A)
     * @param b         The second argument (of type B)
     *
     * @return          A Pair of A and B
     */
    public static <A,B> Pair<A,B> of(A a, B b)
    {
        return new Pair<>(a,b);
    }


    // Don't forget to get your IDE to produce a hashcode() 
    // and equals() method for you, depending
    // on if you allow nulls or not, or DIY.

}
```

Answer (score -1):

it could help. You can use a for each like below.

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("hello1", new String("Hello"));
        map.put("hello2", new String("World"));
        map.put("hello3", new String("How"));
        map.put("hello4", new String("Are u"));

        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> e: map.entrySet()){
             System.out.println(e.getKey());
        }
```

Comment: The question specifies that "Iterating all entries or keys doesn't count."